# Web page that links all files in a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to build a ruby web page that **dynamically** links all files in a directory. Does anyone have any sample code or basic suggestions as to how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html) class, either with `Dir.entries` to list the directory, or with `Dir.glob` for a bit more flexibility. Keep in mind that `entries` gives you names only, while `glob` will include the full relative path.

You could use an action like this:

```
def index
  root = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public"
  @files = Dir.entries(root).reject {|x| x.match /^\./}
end
```

And a view:

```
<% @files.each do |path| %>
  <li><a href="<%= path %>">
         <%= File.basename path %></a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Very nice, I appreciate the answer, That was the direction I was going, but you saved me a lot of trial and error. Thanks!